# Adding a penalty or weighting values differently

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, pulp

I have a minimization problem that I am trying to solve for, and specifically trying to better understand PulP in Python with settings/preferences when trying to solve the optimization problem.

Here is a dummy problem.

We are trying to minimize which orders gets us to a minimum total value. We also want to try and get more orders whose Days are lower (ie: orders 2 & 3 should be chosen over picking order 5)

For ex: if our goal to get to a Total Value <= 50 then I prefer to choose orders 2 & 3 as opposed to order 5 since Days are higher for order 5.

I am just uncertain how to add this constraint or penalty to a PulP minimization problem.

Here is the code I am using:

```
from pulp import *
import pandas as pd

orders_dict_dummy = {"Orders": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                     "Value": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                     "Days": [1, 2, 2, 3, 5],
                     "Participants": [5, 5, 6, 10, 10]}

new_df = pd.DataFrame(orders_dict_dummy)

orders_ = list(new_df['Orders'])
costs = dict(zip(orders_, orders_dict_dummy["Value"]))
days = dict(zip(orders_, orders_dict_dummy["Days"]))
days_list = list(new_df['Days'])

# setup problem
prob = LpProblem("Simple Orders Problem", LpMinimize)

# create Var
order_vars = LpVariable.dicts("Orders", orders_, lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat="Integer")

#objective function
prob += lpSum([costs[i] * order_vars[i] for i in orders_]

# set constraint
prob += lpSum([costs[f] * order_vars[f] for f in orders_]) >= 50

prob.solve()
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible approaches:

1. Maximize for one objective (total value), then add the result as a constraint and solve for the other objective (total days).
2. Make the objective a weighted sum, where total value has the larger weight.

**Edit**: Following the 2nd approach you could make a small modification to your objective:

```
#objective function
total_cost = lpSum([costs[i] * order_vars[i] for i in orders_])
total_days = lpSum([days[i] * order_vars[i] for i in orders_])

prob += 100*total_cost + total_days
```

where `100` is used to put emphasis on minimizing the total cost.

After solving you can show the results like:

```
print(f"total_cost = {total_cost.value():.1f}")
print(f"total_days = {total_days.value():.1f}")

for v in prob.variables():
    if v.varValue > 0:
        print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
```

I get:

```
total_cost = 50.0
total_days = 4.0
Orders_1 = 1.0
Orders_4 = 1.0
```

Comment: Interesting approach for option #2. Any good references you could provide or assistance on that?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization. General guidance for the trade-off between your different objectives is hard to give.

Comment: how would you do this in pulp? Unfortunately Ive had trouble finding a good example online similar to my case

Comment: I added an example to the answer